# useEffect() keeps re-rendering, how to stop it from re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, okta, okta-react-native

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { theme } from "./theme-default";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { GlobalStyle } from "./themes";
import { Security } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { OktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-auth-js";

import { FeeSitePageHeader } from "./app/fee--site-page-header";
import { FeeSitePageFooter } from "./app/fee-site-page-footer";
import Dashboard from "./app/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Logout from "./app/Logout/Logout";
import Login from "./app/Login/Login";


function App() {
  const config = {
    issuer: 'https://dev-95779092.okta.com/', 
    clientId: '***',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/?redirect_url=/login/callback'
  };

  const authClient = new OktaAuth(config); 

  function restoreOriginalUri()  {
    console.log(restoreOriginalUri);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Router >
      <FeeSitePageHeader />
      <Security oktaAuth={authClient}  restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Security>
      <FeeSitePageFooter />
      </Router>
     </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the dashboard component.

```
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import React from 'react';

import * as Styled from "./Dashboard.styled";

function Dashboard(){
    const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
        if (window.location.search?.includes('redirect_url=/login/callback')) {
          console.log("Check if the browser contains redirect");
        }

    }, [])

    return(
        <>
        <Styled.CardsWrapper>Apple</Styled.CardsWrapper>
        <Styled.CardsWrapper>Apple</Styled.CardsWrapper>
        <Styled.CardsWrapper>Apple</Styled.CardsWrapper>
        <Styled.CardsWrapper>Apple</Styled.CardsWrapper>
        <Styled.CardsWrapper>Apple</Styled.CardsWrapper>
        <Styled.CardsWrapper>Apple</Styled.CardsWrapper>
        </>
       
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

When the application starts, call goes to OKTA, authenticate logic does its part and url changes to "http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard?redirect_url=/login/callback". After this I want useEffects to get called, Problem is Dashboard keeps re-rendering itself how to stop re-rendering here?

Comment: i think you should remove this line from dashboard `oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();`

Comment: @ion If I remove that login would not work

Comment: Is your question/issue basically still the same issue you had from your other question [here](/q/73398797/8690857)? Obviously the Okta redirect is the issue if it's mutating the `window.location` object. This is reloading the page and thus reloading your app. This means the entire app is unmounted and mounted, so all mounting `useEffect` hooks will run. Are there any Okta APIs that don't redirect? I noticed this in your other question but didn't call it out, but you probably don't want to create a new `authClient` any time `App` rerenders. Either move it out of the component or into an effect.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, I was able to fix it with your and others help.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs when you are using the functional component you shouldn't recreate the octaAuth every time.

https://github.com/okta/okta-react#creating-react-router-routes-with-function-based-components

Then you call signInWithRedirect in useEffect every time when component mounts. It should be wrapped with `authState.isAuthenticated`. Example in docs https://github.com/okta/okta-react#show-login-and-logout-buttons-function-based

Comment: when I add this, I see the below error,
if(oktaAuth.isAuthenticated())

This condition will always return true since this 'Promise<boolean>' is always defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the URL you "reload" the page hence - useEffect runs again.

Comment: how can I redirect in the if loop and make sure useEffect doesn't run again?

Comment: don't reload the page. change the state or use internal routes

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the parameter inside the useEffect hook**

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
      oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
       if (window.location.search?.includes('redirect_url=/login/callback')) {
         console.log("Check if the browser contains redirect");
       }

     }, [authState])
```

Comment: doesn't work, still keeps re-rendering